# Is There a Way to Run Kindle Fire Emulator on OS X Mavericks?

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, osx-mavericks, kindle-fire

I updated my machine to `OS X Mavericks` and I wanted to run a `Kindle Fire Emulator` but it doesn't run at all.

I ran the `Amazon AVD Launcher` for `OS X` and it worked fine. I created an emulator and started it and my machine freezes.

I also tried to install `Windows 7` using `Parallels Desktop 9` and downloaded the `Amazon AVD Launcher` for `Windows` and I ran it. My machine didn't freeze but it also didn't run the emulator.

Is there any way to resolve this issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know if you have the latest Intel HAXM drivers installed?  That step usually gets missed by folks.  =)  I did a  walkthrough on our Amazon Developer Blog you may find helpful here: http://developer.amazon.com/post/TxHLJ1TU9TX9N6/Harness-the-Speed-and-Power-of-the-New-Kindle-Fire-HD-Emulators-with-Amazon-AVD.html

There is also a known issue with Mavericks and the HAXM driver that requires a hotfix.  Here is a direct link to the latest HAXM driver and the hotfix for Mavericks and Windows 8.1: http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager/

As long as you have the Intel HAXM driver and latest hotfix (and assuming the required hardware) you should be able to run both the Amazon AVD Launcher and Android Emulators using GPU Host and Intel x86 support.

Thanks,

Dave